# How to compare Angular Flex Layout to Bootstrap 4 grid system?

Tags: css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I'm used to work with Bootstrap and for me the grid system is very clear in my head. Now, I'm trying to use the Angular Flex Layout and, even reading the documentation, I'm not understanding how exactly to use it.

For instance, I have the following code using Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
      Something...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
      Something...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
      Something...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I write the same code using Angular Flex Layout??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In angular-flex-layout we don't have a grid so you would have to approach it this way to achieve same result as using bootstrap grid system:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap"
     fxLayout.sm="column"  >

    <div fxFlex.lg="33.333%" fxFlex.md="66.667%"  fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" style="background-color:red">
        first-section
    </div>
    <div fxFlex.lg="33.333%" fxFlex.md="66.667%"  fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" style="background-color:blue">
        second-section
    </div>
    <div fxFlex.lg="33.333%" fxFlex.md="66.667%"  fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" style="background-color:yellow">
        third-section
    </div>
</div>
```

do mind that responsive break points could be different.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, its exactly what i need. How about the <div class="container"> from Bootstrap? Is there a similar way to represent It using flex layout?

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida No, unfortunately it doesn't offer you those type of stuff, it is only there to help you with using flex as tag attributes  instead of doing those in css your self.

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki, here is very specific documentation, which also contains some few stackblitz demos so you can go on them and play around